# How is the batcave kept clean?

Tags: dc, batman

In recent time I've noticed the Batcave is always incredibly clean, but inside the Batcave are living bats.  How does Batman keep it clean from the [guano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guano) ? or does Alfred work all the  day cleaning the poo?

Comment: They make it into [pottery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM8Df0NjEGo)

Comment: A fleet of Roombas!

Comment: Tiny bats, in maid outfits.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Not just any Roombas, Bat-Roombas :-)

Comment: I mean...he's got a butler...

Comment: That would be the Bat Broom?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The extensive cave system underneath Wayne Manor is quite large. No doubt when Batman started placing equipments and lighting into the Batcave the bats were compelled to go deeper into the cave (or further from Batman's operations).

The various changes to the environment caused by the equipment, primarily noise and temperature, would have made for a less desirable living space for most of the bats. They just relocated to a different part of the caverns.

I recall once where Alfred became ill due to frequent exposure to bat guano.

**There are other uses:**

http://www.bizarro.com/

[image: from Bizarro, by Dan Piraro]

http://www.myextralife.com/comic/todays-comic-holy-bat-rejects/
[image]

Comment: I recall seeing an issue in the Bruce Wayne: Murderer? storyline where Alfred talks about cleaning the bats' dejects. Can't recall the exact issue or quote, though,

Answer (score 11):

In the DC universe superheroes never have to stop to use the restroom.  This applies to the bats in the Batcave too, unless the plot dictates otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

According to the DC Visual Dictionary, the bats were a constant nuisance to

> "*Alfred's fastidious cleaning*"

So the short answer is that **Alfred** was responsible for cleaning the Batcave, along with shoveling bat poop.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to *Blue Beetle* vol. 7, issue #7, the floors at least can just be sprayed with a hose.

[image: Jaime Reyes apologises for throwing up in the Batcave and Batman says the floors hose clean.]

(By "people", he definitely means "sidekicks", doesn't he?)