# Is the Batcave bat-friendly?

Tags: dc, batman

In the recent Dark Knight Trilogy, Bruce Wayne re-discovers the underground cave in his manor and then installs lights there as the first step towards building the Batcave. This leads me to the question:

Are the lights and the rest of the Batcave installation bat-friendly, or does the whole setup adversely affect the bats? A character like the Batman must care about animals and the environment; especially ones that inspire his own persona. Did Batman care about how his hideout affected the bats? Is there any treatment of or allusion to the relationship between Batman and the bats living in the Batcave in any of the comics or any other works?

Comment: And the silly thing about that is that batman doesn't need the lights either.

Comment: After reading both the existing answers, it seems that while the works show bats in the batcave, in real-life terms it isn't really bat friendly. i.e. the effects of the activities in the cave are ignored, since this is a work of fiction.

Comment: There are deeper parts of the Batcave that batman doesn't use, I imaging those deep recesses did not receive additional lighting, which is where the bats take their primary residence when they are not out-and-about.

Comment: "A character like the Batman must care about animals" -- _must?_ The character of Batman is trying to save Gotham City, not Gotham City's Wildlife.

Comment: @GorchestopherH, true about the Batcave being big and the bats living in other areas, but if the bats inhabit these other recesses, might imply that they can't co-habitate the parts Batman is using (they have been forced out of some areas). While they can still live in the cave, doesn't seem Batman cares to make the place bat-fiendly.

Comment: @Deion You'll find that almost nothing designed or modified for human utility is equally suitable for bats, excepting an attic perhaps. Batman didn't exterminate the co-habiting bats, but he certainly didn't feel the need to leave their habitat completely intact.

Comment: A character like Batman must care about animals and the environment? Say what? This is the @#%^&! Batman here, not freakin' Captain Planet!

Comment: @ArjunShankar "the effects of the activities in the cave are ignored, since this is a work of fiction"? Something being fiction doesn't mean cause and effect is ignored, despite the amount of ignoring and ignorance that often goes on, particularly in Hollywood. Some sort of cause and effect is necessary to have any continuity or comprehensibility at all. The choice and ability of an author is of course limited to certain things. But "it has no effect because it's fiction" is never accurate.

Comment: @BrianS: [Some bat species are legally protected](http://www.dec.ny.gov/animals/81531.html). Batman's whole *raison d'etre* as crime-fighter would surely compel him to enforce wildlife protection laws.

Comment: @AE, Batman is hardly the most lawful hero in comic or movies.

Comment: @BrianS, my Batman knowledge is very limited, but presumably when he breaks the law he's doing so in pursuit of a more important goal, usually relating to law-enforcement? I mean he doesn't go around parking in disabled spaces or shoplifting (or disturbing protected species) just for the hell of it, surely? Or does he?

Comment: @BrianS, you misunderstood me. The word "must" isn't always used to represent a formal requirement. It can be used to imply a subjective personal opinion. And based on my experience with works of art related to the Batman, I think it is reasonable to assume that he would care about them in some sort of way. They inspire him, after all.

Comment: @Dronz Thanks for trying to explain what you did. But I never said that all cause and effect are ignored in works of fiction. But this one might be.

Comment: I am amazed by the seriousness and effort put in by this community in answering and commenting on my question. Thank you so much! I am still unsure which answer is the best fit and so this question remains unmarked as "answered" for now.

Comment: "unmarked as answered"?

Comment: Also, [this might be related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18074/32339): "The various changes to the environment caused by the equipment, primarily noise and temperature, would have made for a less desirable living space for most of the bats. They just relocated to a different part of the caverns." Coexistence doesn't imply that the place is friendly, just that the bats endure.

Comment: In regards to breaking the law, I'm pretty sure Batman parks wherever the heck he wants to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's established in [Batman #655](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_655) that **Alfred** is in charge of tending to the needs of the bats in the roof of the Batcave.

Since it's a heavy part of the established canon that "**The Batcave contains bats**" (along with "**Bruce's parents are dead**" and "**Bruce Wayne is Batman**") I think we can reasonably assume that the Batcave in the Nolan trilogies is similarly bat friendly.

[image]

Purely FYI: The DC Visual dictionary notes that the bats in question are American Brown Bats

> "though the scores of American Brown Bats (Myotis lucifugus) perched
>   high above the Batcave floor were a nuisance to Alfred's fastidious
>   cleaning..."

Comment: As yummy as Alfred's cooking sounds, I'm not sure what kind of bat's would eat that.  Most species of bat's I'm familiar with eat 1) Fruit or 2)Mosquitos...I don't know of any bats that eat chicken

Comment: @Brouellette The ones that would inspire a grown man to dress up in fancy Pjs and wander the town at night fighting bad guys.

Comment: @MatthewGreen - Canonically, they're American brown bats, according to various batman comics.

Comment: @Richard, which are insectivores...

Comment: @BrianS -Don't be coming in here with your facts and common sense. You'll find that those aren't welcome in these parts... :-P

Comment: Maybe Alfred's chicken goujons rot and attract bugs which the bats eat. Do American Brown Bats eat flies? ;-)

Comment: @Dronz - Flies are not generally attracted to chives.

Comment: Then the question that remains is "why we never see the batmobile (or the lab) covered in batshit?" It does not look like there is any physical obstacle for the bats to fly over them.

Comment: If I may quote from the DC Visual Dictionary : *"though the scores of American Brown Bats (Myotis lucifugus) perched high above the Batcave floor were a nuisance to Alfred's fastidious cleaning..."*; http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090305005730/marvel_dc/images/e/e1/Batcave_010.jpg

Comment: I think Alfred was making a small joke here.

Comment: The only thing I find unbelievable about those panels is that Batman didn't KNOW Alfred was feeding the bats. C'mon... he's Batman.

Comment: I am sure that Alfred, being Alfred, will be fully aware of the dietary requirements of whichever species of Master Bruce's nocturnal friends inhabit the Batcave. I agree with Gustav. It's a bat-joke :-)

Answer (score 20):

Nolan's Dark Knight trilogy portraits a non-*batfriendly* batcave.

Bats, as most nocturnal animals, have very sensitive eyes. Bright lights would stress them and can potentially harm the bats' sensitive eyes, blinding them.

Thus said, if Batman is making an entrance like this in Dark Knight Rises

he is probably scaring to death all the animals, maybe blinding more than one with the lights of his vehicle... Shall there be any bats, of course. No bats are seen in this scene or any other depicting the Batcave in Dark Knight Rises. Given the constructions the batcave has undergone between Batman Begins and DK Rises, you could wonder if all the bats living there had to leave during the works.

The bats in the batcave in Batman Begins wouldn't be doing much better. I'm yet to find a video to show this, but right when Batman is leaving to fight Ras at the end (after Wayne Manor is burnt) we see Batman getting ready, picking some of his gadgets, and then leaving in the Batmobile. Right before leaving the batmobile's lights scare some bats in the wall. Again, this animals could have been permanently blinded.

So I would say that the Nolanverse Batman is not that thoughtful with the inhabitants of the cave.

Comment: That said, technically none of the incarnations of the batcave are really animal friendly.  Batman keeps all of his vehicles somewhere in the cave.  Just the sound of the engines of these vehicles would cause problems for the bats, plus, they also use lights as well.  So I'd have to add to your answer in saying that no, the batcave is not bat friendly at all.

Comment: Since the bat cave *does* contain bats, it seems that they somehow adapted to the issues you've raised.

Comment: I disagree, the cave is quite big and the lights are not pointing up to the top of the cave which is where the bats are staying. I highly doubt batman installed pod lights at the top of the batcave. It also depends on what kind of bats they have in there. I am no expert in bats but I have seen bats flying around during day time on one of the Maldive islands during my honeymoon.

Comment: @Huangism, I didn't say daylight would blind a bat, but a strong light could permanently blind them. Definitely they would not like it, and would be affected by Batman vehicles' noises and lights. I don't think that there is any proof that Bruce cares in any special way about the inhabitants of the batcave in this trilogy, and I don't recall seeing any in the batcave in DK Rises. I agree the cave is big, and the bats could be in a different part, but then Bats and Batman are not sharing space, so we can't say Bruce cares about them.

Comment: I have to point that even if bats adapted to this issues, is their own "merit" and not something Alfred or Batman are making in consideration to these bats.

Comment: @Deion As I mentioned, the bats are on the ceilings on a huge cave. The lights from Batman's vehicle does not shine to the ceiling so the lights would not disturb them. As for the noise, it's only once in awhile that he will drive out or fly out. Bats have different hearing than humans and it is known that bats have roosted in common human built structures. As for if Batman actually care for the bats, I don't know but I don't think he needs to feed them. They lived in the cave before without feeding, I am sure they can still eat now that Batman is there

Comment: I'm skeptical that bright lights permanently blind bats. What about the sun? What about lightning? Do you have a citation?

Comment: @PhilFrost, [Artificial light puts ecosystem services of frugivorous bats at risk](http://physics.fau.edu/observatory/lightpol-Mammals.html): "Nocturnal bats have only rods cells in their retinas. Bats are not truly blind (they do have eyes), but are actually blinded by bright lights. Hence they are highly sensitive to lights". [Bright lights may repel bats](http://www3.ag.purdue.edu/entm/wildlifehotline/pages/bats.aspx) etc. Is not that lightning will permanently blind them (bats would still feed from the insects attracted to a street lamp) but their eyes are *very* sensitive to bright lights

Comment: @PhilFrost, Bats are not blind. They can differentiate day from night and become active. Also, I'm not implying that the sun at dusk or lighting would blind them, but the powerful lights of the Batmobile or Bat could severely damage the sensitive eyes of nocturnal animals. At least it would put them in distress, so I'm more prone to believe that they don't like the noise and lights of Batman's rides that they are indifferent to them.

Comment: @Deion I wasn't disputing that lights aren't problematic for bats, just that *permanent* blindness seems unlikely. Now that you've removed "permanent" from the answer, I find it more feasible. However, I would still suggest editing to include the links in your comments in the answer where more people will see them.

Answer (score 5):

@Richard's answer clearly establishes that bats were at one time present in the Batcave. If there has been substantial construction work since then, the [bats would need to have been relocated](http://www.ehow.com/how_4448888_relocate-bats.html); they could not possibly have survived *in situ* with major renovations going on.

But [building a bat house](http://www.nwf.org/How-to-Help/Garden-for-Wildlife/Gardening-Tips/Build-a-Bat-House.aspx) is quite easy and inexpensive (even quite a large bat house should be affordable for BW) and would be a logical precursor to the renovations.

So evidently the reason the bats are no longer visible in the movies is that they've been relocated to a bat-house in a safer and quieter part of the Batcave with less vehicles, visitors, bright lights, etc.

If they do live in a bat-house then it must surely be known as the Bat-bat-house.

Or on a less optimistic note, perhaps they've succumbed to white-nose syndrome, which seems to be endemic in Gotham City:

> We have yet to find a cure for the disease known as white-nose syndrome, which has decimated populations of hibernating, ***cave-dwelling bats in the Northeast***. ...
>
> White-nose syndrome (also known as W.N.S.) was first documented in February 2006 in upstate New York, where it may have been carried from Europe to a ***bat cave*** on an explorer’s hiking boot. In Europe, bats appear to be immune, likely the outcome of a long evolutionary process. But in North America, bats are highly susceptible to the cold-loving fungus that appears in winter on the muzzle and other body parts during hibernation, irritating them awake at a time when there is no food. They end up burning precious stores of energy and starve to death.
>
> The consequences have been **catastrophic**. A 2011 study of 42 sites across five Eastern states found that after 2006 the populations of tri-colored and Indiana bats declined by more than 70 percent, and little brown bats by more than 90 percent. The population of the northern long-eared bat, once common, has declined by an estimated 99 percent and prompted a proposal from the United States Fish and Wildlife Service to list it as an endangered species. Other species of hibernating cave-dwelling bats have **declined precipitously** as well.
>
> Whether these bats will recover or go extinct is unclear.

[**Protect Our Bats**](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/12/opinion/protect-our-bats.html), New York Times, 11 May 2014

[image: White-nose syndrome map]
[Whitenosesyndrome.org](https://www.whitenosesyndrome.org/resources/map), U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service

Comment: Love the expression Bat-bat-house!

Answer (score 4):

Isn't Bruce Wayne afraid of bats? He doesn't fight his fears... he just accepts them or tries to conquer them.

I don't think he will like to make his den 'bat friendly' just for the sake of conquering or accepting his fear.

Comment: It's a pretty common feature of all of the batman comics and films that the batcave has bats. He was afraid of them as **a child** but as an adult, he's conquered his fear and now quite likes them.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be terribly out of character for Bruce Wayne to keep bats around even if they did still freak him out a little, just to test himself and keep from getting complacent.  Bats don't reduce him to tears, but like the adult whose pulse quickens when they cross a pitch-black room but who refuses to turn on the light, he could just be exercising his "mind over matter" techniques.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to find a definitive image, but we should probably keep in mind that the Bat-cave is a very large system of connected caves/tunnels.

While parts of the Batcave do have the bright lights, computers and vehicles, there are other less easily accessed parts of the cave that may have been left natural giving safe havens for the bats to hang in.

A good example would be the cavern Bruce first fell into as a boy.  We see in the films that his father had to go get climbing gear to retrieve him, while there already was an entrance from the house to the caves (from the underground railroad).  So why didn't he take the easy way through the tunnel?  In the novelization of Knightfall (I don't have the comic on hand so I'm just going to reference the book) when Bruce fights Jean Paul in the Batcave the means to victory comes from going down a too narrow to go through in armor tunnel that leads to the outside via the original hole Bruce fell in as a child.

So here we have at least one tunnel that is too small for vehicles and almost too small for grown men to go through.  That probably means 1) There are others of similar nature and 2)that the too small tunnels don't have equipment nor are the used as access roads for the various bat-vehicles.

Habitats like those probably take care of the noise/light issues.

My biggest concern for the Bats would probably be diseases.  Like @AE brought up. WNS is probably a big concern especially as all those vehicles are bringing in soil from distant locations (which are often caves as well).  Rabies may also be an issue.