# What kind of bats live in the Batcave in Christopher Nolan's Batman?

Tags: batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, dc

Near the start of Batman Begins young Bruce Wayne falls down a well and gets attacked by bats. Later we meet the bats again when he first discovers the bat cave and in one scene Batman uses the bats to destroy a Swat team. Is there any evidence of what type of bat they are in-universe. Does the habitat or extremely strong swarming and mobbing response to humans suggest what species they might be?

Comment: Same question on Yahoo Answers: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090608144124AAhPJ4S

Comment: That only answers for out of universe. I'm looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: The ones in the Visual Dictionary are "American Brown Bats"; as noted in [Is the Batcave bat-friendly?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/is-the-batcave-bat-friendly) Obviously this refers to the comic serial and not the film, but it's reasonable to assume that they're the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### American Brown Bats

> The vast caverns had once been used to shelter runaway slaves escaping
>   to the North. Damp limestone walls glistened beneath the subdued
>   interior lighting that Bruce had installed years ago. A shallow,
>   slow-moving river was all that remained of the underground waterway
>   that had carved out the caverns in ages past. Massive wooden arches,
>   high overhead, helped to support the mansion’s foundations.
>
> Scores of North American brown bats roosted amidst the jagged
>   stalactites hanging from the ceiling. Towering calcite columns rose
>   hundreds of feet in height. The bats squeaked and rustled overhead.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Dark Knight Rises: Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13536475-the-dark-knight-rises)</sup></sub>

This tallies nicely with what we know from other sources, notably the DC Visual Dictionary

> *"though the scores of American Brown Bats (Myotis lucifugus) perched high above the Batcave floor were a nuisance to Alfred's fastidious
>   cleaning..."*"

[image]