# Has Batman's equipment ever become faulty from being stored in the Batcave?

Tags: dc, batman

The Batcave is filled with unique vehicles, gadgets, and state-of-the-art computers. It seems odd to store this valuable equipment in a cave that is cold, damp, and filled with bats all the time.

Batman also depends on his equipment in life and death situations on a regular basis. Has equipment ever broken down on the job because of being stored in the Batcave? What does he do to prevent his equipment from becoming damaged while stored there?

Comment: I assume Alfred dusts that stuff once in a while, so no.

Comment: Whenever he drives the Batmobile, the flames shooting out the back heat and dry the atmosphere *just* enough. He also has an agreement with the bats that they leave "his side" of the cave alone in exchange for free rent.

Comment: If batman can install a billion dollar computer system he can probably hook up a dehumidifier as well.

Answer (score 5):

This answer (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135240/42237), which cites the DC Visual Dictionary, mentions Alfred's "**fastidious cleaning**". It can be surmised that Alfred kept the Batcave and its equipment as pristine as possible to avoid any guano-related malfunctions.

Answer (score 2):

Caves are not necessarily "cold, damp, and filled with bats".

- Being underground tends to moderate the temperature.
- Dampness would only result from a source of water.
- While some bats live in caves, the Batcave does not seem to be one of them.

The U.S. certainly has commercial storage areas housed in caves that are used precisely because they remain warm in winter and cool in summer, and have relatively low humidity. Those characteristics make them particularly suitable for storing "unique vehicles, gadgets, and state-of-the-art computers".

Answer (score 1):

Is it called the Batcave because it is a bat inhabited bat cave or because it is Batman's possession like the Batmobile, Batcopter, Batplane, Batboat, bat etc., etc.?

If there aren't any bats living in Batman's cave in a particular version there is no bat guano to worry about in that version.  Or possibly there is a dividing wall between Batman's stuff and the bat habitat.

Possibly the Batcave is climate controlled with heat, air conditioning, dust filters and dehumidifiers and humidifiers as needed.  Thus the equipment would be just fine in there.

Comment: I don't recall any version of the cave that didn't have actual bats in it. That's kinda Bruce's thing.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is only speculation.

Comment: @SonOfSam True, but it doesn't really make much sense for this highly secure facility to be infested with bats. Bats need to be able to leave their cave to drink water and hunt insects. OTOH, you'd want the Batmobile, Batcomputer, Batplane, etc. to be sealed inside of a secure chamber with heavy duty doors. If I were Batman, I'd keep all the bats in an outer chamber with easy access to the open air but keep all my toys in a deeper chamber where the bats can't crap on on them.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté See my comment above. There could be a his-side-their-side arrangement.

Comment: @SonOfSam Bats are apparently much better tenants than most humans. I can barely get my roommate to flush the toilet after himself.